# MongoDB: WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index, failing 1719: (Mongo Version: 4.0.3)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to insert long string to Mongodb via Node (Mongoose as ODM), Failing causing the error mentioned in title.

Tried inserting the string via Terminal, MongoDB Compass but no luck.

```
 driver: true,
  name: 'MongoError',
  index: 0,
  code: 17280,
  errmsg:
   'WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index, failing  1719
```

The String needs to be inserted without any index loss.
Running Mongo 4.0.3

Answer (score 2):

Created a Hashed Index on that key using:

`db.collection.createIndex( { _id: "hashed" } )`

Now it is successfully inserting. But do we have any other solution ?